# Calling a function many times in a very short interval

Tags: ios

I'll call a function many times in a very short time, and this function will not be executed on main thread.

For example, I'll call 5 times in one second. My requirement is:

1. The 1st call should be executed immediately.
2. The last call (5th) should be executed, other calls can be ignored.
3. One time one call, shouldn't execute this function on two threads at the same time.

So how?

Comment: That sounds great. Go ahead and do that. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.

1. Wrap you function into NSOperation.
2. You can make NSOperationQueue **serial** and cancelAllOperations when add new
   NSOperation in it.
3. Your operations will be executed in some
   NSOperationQueue you've created so they will be on same thread ;)

Here is Apple docs for concurrency and NSOperation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html